# Is there any way to show the hidden files at the end of Finder's file list?

Tags: finder, macos

I have Finder set to display hidden files/folders. This is rather inconvenient when I open my home folder however, given it contains a lot of them.

[image: Lots of hidden files/folders!]

Is there a way to change the alphabetical sorting of Finder's file list, so that it sorts files beginning with "." at the end of the current file-list?

It's a longshot, but you never know.

Comment: That's a new one, Sort by Hidden files. Lets look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to arrange by Kind in Finder.

That would put the hidden files at the end marked as Others and in Alphabetical order. The folders are also organized, see example.

[image: Finder sort]