# Sort files by hidden value in finder (Big Sur)

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

As simple as that : is there a way to sort files in my finder by hidden value (say all hidden files and directories will be on the bottom of my finder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to show the hidden files at the end of Finder's file list?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126571/is-there-any-way-to-show-the-hidden-files-at-the-end-of-finders-file-list)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. Finder only knows how to sort by Name, Type, Timestamps, Size and Tags.